# Android fake touch interface

Tags: android, interface, touch

can anyone explain me what does this feature gives me :
**android.hardware.faketouch.multitouch.distinct**
The description says: The application performs distinct tracking of two or more "fingers" on a fake touch interface. This is a superset of the faketouch feature.

I want to know what this fake touch interface is? And is it possible to make a application for a real android phone which includes this fake touch interface. Because i need to make a application which will recognize up to 6 touches simultaneously.

Thank you all for the help, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faketouch :

```
"A fake touch interface provides a user input system that emulates a subset of touchscreen capabilities.
For example, a mouse or remote control that drives an on-screen cursor provides a fake touch interface."
```

For more understanding read [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_FAKETOUCH_MULTITOUCH_DISTINCT) & [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#hw-features).

Comment: Thank you Android Coader, this helped me.